# Which angular 2 release version is more stable for production?

Tags: angular

Which release is the most stable to use for angular 2 production app? 
For example 2.1.0 is more stable than 2.0.0? Or it's the same?

Comment: Latest is considered to be most stable. You can see about the changes between the versions in change log.

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray OK, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Angular-2.0.2`** is stable. So, You can use it.

check here : https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Now, Angular2 is going thorugh -  **`2.1.0- RC`** phase(s)...

Comment: thank you. -RC means that is not stable yet?

Comment: Google says, A release candidate (RC) is a beta version with potential to be a final product, which is ready to release unless significant bugs emerge. In this stage of product stabilization, all product features have been designed, coded and tested through one or more beta cycles with no known showstopper-class bugs. I hope you can understand it.

Comment: I understand it. Thanks a lot.